# Unable to show Mongodb collection data into angular2 using ngFor with angular2 meteor

Tags: mongodb, angular, angular2-meteor

I am very new to mongodb. I am basically trying to retrieve data from a collection and put to screen. Its an angular2-meteor app. I can insert and retrieve data inside the mongo shell. But when I try to loop through the value bookmarks i get the error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

When i console log the returned data from the find() method, it returns the entire mongodb objects collection and the boomarks collection is deeply buried inside the object.

How can I get an array of all the objects inside the returned bookmarks variable returned using the .find() method?

My component is as below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './bookmarks.component.html';
import { Bookmarks } from '../../../../collections/bookmarks';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
@Component({
  selector: 'bookmarks-list',
  template
})
export class bookmarksListComponent {
  bookmarks: Mongo.Cursor<Object>;
  constructor() {
    this.bookmarks=Bookmarks.find();
    console.log(this.bookmarks);
  }
}
```

here is the html template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let bookmark of bookmarks">
        <td>{{bookmark.title}}</td>
        <td>{{bookmark.url}}</td>
        <td>{{bookmark.category}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoKFY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Found out the solution using rxjs: 
Instead of working with meteor/mongo, use rxjs and subscribe to the collections.find() method of mongo. Also while newing up the mongo collection use MongoObservable.collections entire code:

**bookmarks.component.ts:**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import template from './bookmarks.component.html';
import { Bookmarks, bookmark } from '../../../../collections/bookmarks';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'bookmarks-list',
  template
})
export class bookmarksListComponent implements OnInit{
  private bookmarks: bookmark[];
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    Bookmarks.find({}).zone().subscribe({
      next: bookmarks => {
        console.log("Got Bookmarks: ", bookmarks);
        this.bookmarks=bookmarks;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Bookmarks.ts (collections)**

```
import { MongoObservable } from 'meteor-rxjs';
export interface bookmark {
    title: string;
    url: string;
    category: string;
}
export const Bookmarks= new MongoObservable.Collection<bookmark>('bookmarks');
```

Angular2-rxjs-meteor:
Get help from this repo https://github.com/ijager/meteor-rxjs-angular2.0.0-example.git

Comment: Aint the syntax wrong ? `Bookmarks.find({}).zone().subscribe({` why the `{`  ?

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do it using Mongo.Cursor then  in your code

```
constructor() {
this.bookmarks=Bookmarks.find();
console.log(this.bookmarks);
  }
```

replace `this.bookmarks=Bookmarks.find();`

with `this.bookmarks=Bookmarks.find({}).fetch();`